# SQL condition datetime set

Tags: sqlite

Console have to show information about device_id number 1, coz it didnt update more then 1 year, but i got device_id 1 and 3

I`m sure, that problem at this WHERE last_checking_date + 365 < ’2019.01.09’ AND type = ‘termometr’; but I cant fix it, how to set datetime for my condition

```
CREATE TABLE workspaces ( 
workspace VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, 
device_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES devices(id), 
setup_date DATETIME, 
last_checking_date DATETIME, 
checking_result VARCHAR (255) 
); 

CREATE TABLE devices ( 
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
type VARCHAR (255), 
realize_date DATETIME, 
accuracy FLOAT 
); 

INSERT INTO workspaces (workspace, device_id, setup_date, last_checking_date, checking_result)
VALUES ('plavka_metalla', ‘1’, '1993.01.11', '1993.01.12', 'Perfect');

INSERT INTO workspaces (workspace, device_id, setup_date, last_checking_date, checking_result)
VALUES ('him_zona', ‘2’, '1993.01.21', '2019.01.04', 'Perfect');

INSERT INTO workspaces (workspace, device_id, setup_date, last_checking_date, checking_result)
VALUES ('metallurgiya', ‘3’, '1994.02.24', '2019.01.04', 'Perfect');

INSERT INTO devices (id, type, realize_date, accuracy)
VALUES ('1', 'termometr', '1993.01.20', '0.91');

INSERT INTO devices (id, type, realize_date, accuracy)
VALUES ('2', 'air_checker', '2013.03.07', '0.94');

INSERT INTO devices (id, type, realize_date, accuracy)
VALUES ('3', 'termometr', '2013.09.27', '0.99');

SELECT workspace, device_id, type FROM workspaces INNER JOIN devices ON workspaces.device_id = devices.id WHERE last_checking_date + 365 < ’2019.01.09’ AND type = ‘termometr’;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of storing your date literals as `2019.01.09`, store them as `2019-01-09`.  Then, try using the `date` function in your query:

```
SELECT
    workspace,
    device_id,
    type
FROM workspaces w
INNER JOIN devices d
    ON w.device_id = d.id
WHERE
    DATE(last_checking_date, '+1 years') < '2019.01.09' AND
    type = 'termometr';
```

Note that I am specifically adding 1 year here rather than 365 days, under the assumption that you mean a year.  Leap years, which occur every four years, have 366 days, not 365.